# What graph data structure is used in train function's Chatterbot module?

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

from chatterbot import ChatBot

from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot("BotBot")

trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

trainer.train([

```
"Hi","Hello",

"I wanted to know today's date","Today's date is 11 Dec 2020",

"Thank you for the information","Do you need any more assistance",

"No thank you","Thank you"])
```

while True:

```
request = input("You:")

if request=='Bye' or request =='bye':

    print('Bot:Bye')

    break

else:

    response = chatbot.get_response(request)

    print("Bot:",response)
```

Comment: explain your question more briefly , don't provide only program

Comment: when you train the bot giving inputs does it use adjacency matrix or adjacency list, or am I understanding the trainer.train() function completely wrong

Answer (score 0):

train() function uses directed graph traversal while giving a response.